# Spring Boot with Rest API 404

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

API working without spring-boot, but with spring-boot, it is not.

```
@RequestMapping("/operationsOnEmployee")

    @RestController
    public class OperationsOnEmployee {

        @Autowired
        EmployeeFacade employeeFacade;

        @GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
        public List<Employee> getEmployee() {
            System.out.println("hello");
            return employeeFacade.getAllEmployee();
        }
```

---

*application.properties*

```
server.port:8080
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

---

> ```
>     "timestamp": "2019-08-01T11:34:07.631+0000",
>     "status": 404,
>     "error": "Not Found",
>     "message": "No message available",
>     "path": "/operationsOnEmployee"
> ```

Comment: post your package structure and application class that scan all the packages

Comment: i have not put my main file and controller in the same package. now it is working fine.

Comment: after putting the file in the same package now its working right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
@GetMapping(value= "/operation", produces = "application/json")
```

Call

```
GET:   localhost:8080/operationsOnEmployee/operation
```

Also, make sure you *don't* have any path defined in *application.properties*

```
server.servlet.context-path= #some path
```

Comment: @mayursinghal, Have you added as per the last edit, do you have any `server.servlet.context-path`. Also update the question with your last changes

Comment: Hello @mayursinghal change `path` with `value` as in updated answer

Comment: path with value . where to change

Comment: @mayursinghal use `@GetMapping(value= "/operation", produces = "application/json")`

Comment: @mayursinghal everything seems fine for now, you may add more details or can share git link

Comment: @mayursinghal before that try to clean and rebuild the project and try again

Comment: actually i have not put my main file and controller in the same package. now it is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try to provide mapping URL inside @GetMapping to map your method as :

```
@GetMapping("/mappingURL")
```

GET URL : localhost:8080/operationsOnEmployee/mappingURL

If not clean the project and re-run

Comment: In Above Answer @Patel mention what is the exact procedure.Try to give good Answer.